# Java Null Pointer Exception for int array?

Tags: java, arrays, genetic-algorithm

Currently working on a GA for the game puzzles and dragons, and keep running into this issue where I cannot create valid individuals because I cannot create a valid child. The issue always falls back onto where the individual tries to find the positions of the 2d array and comes back a null pointer exception in the Array Traverse function.

```
 public class Individual {

  static int MoveLength = 5;
  int fitness = 0;
  boolean Feasibility = true;

ArrayList<Integer> Move = new ArrayList();
public int[] position = new int[2];
char[][] PuzzleMatrix;


public void GenerateIndividual(){
    PositionRandomizer();
    RandomMoves();
    MoveFollower();
   // PrintMatrix(PuzzleMatrix);
    if(this.Feasibility == false){
        GenerateIndividual();
    }
    System.out.println("sucess");
}   


public Individual(char[][] PuzzleMatrix){
    PuzzleMatrix = this.PuzzleMatrix;
}

public void MoveFollower(){
    for(int x = 0; x < Move.size(); x++){
        ArrayTraverse(Move.get(x));
    }
}

public int randomnumbergenerator(){
    int[] myArray = {0,1,2,3};
    Random generator = new Random();
    int randomIndex = generator.nextInt(myArray.length);
    return myArray[randomIndex];
}

public void PositionRandomizer(){
    /*
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range
    random position value
    */
    Random ran = new Random();
    int random = ran.nextInt(7);
    Random ran2 = new Random();
    int random2 = ran2.nextInt(7);      
    position[0] = random;
    position[1] = random2;
}

public void RandomMoves(){
    for(int x = 0; x < MoveLength; x++){
        int randomMove = randomnumbergenerator();
        Move.add(randomMove);
    }       
}

public void ArrayTraverse(int direction){
    System.out.println(direction);
    try{
        if(direction == 0){
            char original = PuzzleMatrix[position[0]][position[1]];
            char newvalue = PuzzleMatrix[position[0] - 1][position[1]];
            PuzzleMatrix[ position[0] - 1 ] [position[1]] = original;
            PuzzleMatrix[ position[0]]     [position[1]] = newvalue;
        }
        if(direction == 2){
            char original = PuzzleMatrix[position[0]][position[1]];
            char newvalue = PuzzleMatrix[position[0] + 1][position[1]];
            PuzzleMatrix[ position[0] + 1 ] [position[1]] = original;
            PuzzleMatrix[ position[0]]     [position[1]] = newvalue;
        }
        if(direction == 1){
            char original = PuzzleMatrix[position[0]][position[1]];
            char newvalue = PuzzleMatrix[position[0]][position[1] + 1];
            PuzzleMatrix[ position[0]] [position[1] + 1 ] = original;
            PuzzleMatrix[ position[0]]     [position[1]] = newvalue;
        }
        if(direction == 3){
            char original = PuzzleMatrix[position[0]][position[1]];
            char newvalue = PuzzleMatrix[position[0]][position[1] - 1];
            PuzzleMatrix[ position[0]] [position[1] - 1 ] = original;
            PuzzleMatrix[ position[0]]     [position[1]] = newvalue;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        Feasibility = false;
    }
}

public void PrintMatrix(char[][] PuzzleMatrix){

    for (int i = 0; i < PuzzleMatrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < PuzzleMatrix[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(PuzzleMatrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: A dup, but also eligible for other close reasons. You have not provided the stack trace nor identified the location in your code that throws.

Comment: The heuristic for NullPointerExceptions is almost always the same. **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me. In the future, please search on the subject before posting, since this is too common a problem to post yet another NPE question.